# JAXB can not handle XML element containing white space to java.net.URI mapping

Tags: java, xml, rest, jaxb, jersey

I have XML like the following:

```
<repository>
<location>/home/username whitespace/somedir</location>
</repository>
```

I am using JAXB to unmarshal this into a JAXB annotated Bean. 
The "location" XML element is mapped to `java.net.URI` class. 
The problem is that when location contains white space, JAXB (or perhaps the underlying XML parser) can't handle this and location is set to `null`. There is no `UnmarshalException` or anything, just `setLocation(URI loc)` is called with a `null` method argument.

A URI without a white space works correctly of course.
The thing is that I can't really change `RepositoryDTO` to say have `String location;` field.

Can you tell what are my options here?

Should I look at URLEncode and then Decode the said `location` field?

This a REST/Jersey use case by the way, although clearly the culprit lies in JAXB/XML parser...

```
    public class Whitespace {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JAXBException {
        String xml = "<repository><location>/home/username whitespace/somedir</location></repository>";

        Unmarshaller createUnmarshaller = JAXBContext.newInstance(RepositoryDTO.class).createUnmarshaller();
        RepositoryDTO repositoryInfo = (RepositoryDTO) createUnmarshaller.unmarshal(new StringReader(xml));
        System.out.println(repositoryInfo.getLocation());

    }

    @XmlRootElement(name = "repository")
    static public class RepositoryDTO {
        private URI location;

        @XmlElement
        public URI getLocation() {
            return location;
        }

        public void setLocation(URI loc) {
            this.location = loc;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this adapter

```
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter;

public class UriAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, URI> {

    public URI unmarshal(String s) {
        if(s != null){
            try {
                return new URI(s.replace(" ", "%20"));
            } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public String marshal(URI uri) {
        return uri.getPath();
    }
}
```

In this way

```
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(UriAdapter.class)
protected URI location;
```

Comment: Accepting this answer, although I'd rather use URLEncoder or similar than doing the encoding myself.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the standart URI encoding for whitespace (replace space inside the XML element with %20)

Comment: Yes, this would work since you'll end up with no white spaces... but why wouldn't JAXB/XML parser just fail if it cannot handle the content? "Mapping" it to null just seems very confusing... Is it null because it has a white space? Or is it null because, well it is null actually, the XML just doesn't contain the "location" element. That is really bugging me :(

Comment: I think the URI is failing in the constuctor since a URI java.net objexts cant have spaces(it is validated in the constructor) - and it would not be leagal. You cant call new URI(someString) if someString contains spaces. Its throws a URINotValidException or whatever the exception is called.