# Ignore some wrapper tags in XML with JAXB 2.0

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

There are two similar questions on SO:

[How to ignore some tags in XML in Jaxb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21727131/how-to-ignore-some-tags-in-xml-in-jaxb)

[JAXB ignoring xml tag attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21188599/jaxb-ignoring-xml-tag-attribute)

But unfortunatelly they don't solve my problem. I'm looking for method how to skip some tags in XML using pure `JAXB` annotations **without `moxy`**.

`@XmlElementWrapper` annotation works only with collecitons. In my case there is something like:

```
<A>
   <skipThisWrapper>
     <someInternalComplexStructure>
       <B>...</B>
       <C>...</C>
     </someInternalComplexStructure>
   </skipThisWrapper>
</A>
```

It should be mapped on class structure:

```
class A {

   // @XmlElementWrapper(name="skipThisWrapper") - it doesn't work for non-collection fields!

   @XmlElement(name='someInternalComplexStructure')
   ComplexStructure complexStructure;
}
```

And yes, I can not turn `complexStructure` to collection because this structure is inherited from some legacy basic classes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write an XmlAdapter that transforms a class A object containing a skipThisWrapper element into a class B object containing the someInternalComplexStructure. This merely requires you to write class B by reusing the class for someInternalComplexStructure and an adapter with the very simple transformations in both directions.

If you have hand-written Java classes it is quite simple, but I refrain from inventing any code. You can find examples for adapters in very recent SO Q&As tagged jaxb ( [Avoid Empty Sub-Tags in XML if everything is blank in an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33526554/avoid-empty-sub-tags-in-xml-if-everything-is-blank-in-an-object) or [JAXB can not handle XML element containing white space to java.net.URI mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33258711/jaxb-can-not-handle-xml-element-containing-white-space-to-java-net-uri-mapping)). If you need help, add some Java code to your Q onto which the adapter can be fitted.

Comment: In this case it could be much easier create own complex logic inside setters and getters: create inner class with `skipThisWrapper` structure and set parrent fields with its inner elements values. I do not see here any advantages of using `XmlAdapter`. Futhermore in my question I've mentioned, that I'm looking for **pure annotations** method for doing such things. In any case thanks for your answer.